# Imagick+php UnableToOpenBlob with mp4 file

Tags: php, windows, video, imagick

I'm trying to make a simple Imagick operation on my local environment, like

```
$im = new Imagick("File.mp4[100]");
```

to prepare video file frame capture. Unfortunately I get a strange exception:

> UnableToOpenBlob `C:/Temp/magick-5924U7hGfaatgEtF.pam': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2657

I've made C:\Temp directory fully writable to "Everybody" - nothing changes.

When I'm running `convert File.mp4[100] File.jpg` from command line operation succeeds, JPG file is generated.

My environment:
PHP Version 5.6.12
Imagick module version  3.1.2
ImageMagick version     ImageMagick 6.8.9-1 Q16 x86 2014-05-08

Comment: Welcome to SO! I made some minor edits to improve your post. Good formatting improves your chances on getting good answers. Furthermore, it is etiquette not to place greetings, thanks, or your name in the post. I hope you'll get some good answers to your questions!

Answer (score 1):

It's likely to be a permissions thing on running the "delegate" that ImageMagick uses to decode video. The way to find out what delegate ImageMagick is using is by running:

```
convert -list Delegate
```

And then finding the one that would be selected for MP4.

I'd suggest trying to run the delegate program through PHP e.g. something like exec("C:/Program Files (x86)/mp4/bin/mp4converter.exe") or whatever program it actually is from inside PHP, and then figure out if that runs successfully or not...